# My function doesn't work and i don't understand why ..in C

Tags: c

I'm working on a problem that keeps the evidence of a shop stock, there is a this part where it is asked to get the code of the product, which I must get by reversing the name of the product.

For example:

```
name of the product : snack
codebar: kcans
```

And everytings works just fine until it gets to the line with `strcpy`.

The menu is not in english but the first one gets the input the second will show the output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct Product
{
    char productName[30];
    char productCode[30];
    int price;
    int stock;
    int date[3];
}P;

char* reverse(char *name)
{
    char aux[30];
    int i,j;

    for(i = strlen(name) - 1, j = 0; i >= 0; i--,j++)
    {
        aux[j] = name[i];
    }
    aux[j] = '\0';

    return aux[30];
}


int nameValidation(char *name)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(name); i++)
    {
        if(name[i] >= 'a' && name[i] <= 'z');
        else
        {
            return 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(i == strlen(name))
    return 1;
}

void input(P *product, int *n)
{
    (*n)++;
    do
    {
        printf("Product name: ");
        scanf("%s", (product + *n)->productName);

    } while (!nameValidation((product + *n)->productName));


    printf("Price: ");
    scanf("%d", &(product + *n)->price);

    printf("Quantity: ");
    scanf("%d", &(product + *n)->sotck);


    do
    {
        printf("Expiration day: ");
        scanf("%d", &(product + *n)->date[0]);

        if((product + *n)->date[0] >= 1 && (product + *n)->date[0] <= 30)
            break;
    } while (1);
   
    
    do
    {
        printf("Expiration month: ");
        scanf("%d", &(product + *n)->date[1]);

        if((product + *n)->date[1] >= 1 && (product + *n)->date[1] <= 12)
            break;
    } while (1);
    

    (product + *n)->date[2] = 2024;
    printf("Expiration Year: %d\n", (product + *n)->date[2]);

    strcpy((product + *n)->productCode, reverse((product + *n)->productName));
    printf("Product Code: %5s\n", (product + *n)->productCode);

}


void output(P *product, int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        printf("Product name: %10s ", (product + i)->productName);

        printf("Price: %5d ", (product + i)->price);

        printf("Stock:%5d\n", (product + i)->stock);
    }

}


int main()
{
    int option;
    int n;
    P product[100];

    n = -1;
    do
    {
        printf("\n0.Iesire\n");
        printf("1.Citirea unui produs de la tastatura\n");
        printf("2.Afisarea produselor citite\n");
        printf("3.Afisarea produselor cu un pret mai mic dat de utilizator\n");
        printf("4.Sa se afiseze toate produsele care au lungimea numelui egala cu un numar par\n");
        printf("5.Afisarea primului produs care este egal cu un nume dat de utilizator\n");
        printf("6.Sa se realizeze produsul cifrelor fiecarui numar de bucati al produselor, apoi sa se copieze fiecare produs intr-un vector si sa se afiseze vectorul.\n");
        printf("7.Copierea tuturor codurilor produselor intr-un vector de sir de caractere, apoi afisare vectorului\n");
        printf("8.Copierea pretului produselor intr-un vector apoi afisarea vectorului in ordine crescatoare\n");
        printf("9.Sa se transforme prima litera din codul produsului in litera mare daca aceasta este vocala.Nu se vor folosii functii predefinite in schimbarea literei\n");
        printf("10.Sa se afiseze forma binara a numarului de bucati ale produselor care au numarul de bucati mai mic decat 100 .\n");
        printf("11.Sa se afiseze toate produsele care urmeaza sa expire in urmatoarele 10 zile.Utilizator va preciza de la tastatura ziua si luna curenta.\n");
        printf("12.Sa se pun pe ultimul rand al unei matrici de caractere de ordin dat de numarul de produse, primul caracter din fieacre nume de produs,pe restul '.'\n");
        printf("13.Stabilirea unui nou pret pt toate produsele daca utilizatorul doreste.Astfel utilizator va stabili procentajul cu care se vor scumpi produsele.\n");
        printf("14.Sa se stearga un produs precizat de utilizator prin numele acestuia\n");
        printf("Introduceti o optiune: ");
        scanf("%d", &optiune);

        switch (option)
        {
        case 1:
            input(product, &n);
            break;
        case 2:
            output(product, n);
            break;
        case 3:
            
            break;
        case 4:
            /* code */
            break;
        case 5:
            /* code */
            break;
        case 6:
            /* code */
            break;
        case 7:
            /* code */
            break;
        case 8:
            /* code */
            break;
        case 9:
            /* code */
            break;
        case 10:
            /* code */
            break;
        case 11:
            /* code */
            break;
        case 12:
            /* code */
            break;
        case 13:
            /* code */
            break;
        case 14:
            /* code */
            break;
        case 0:
            exit(1);
            break;
        
        default:
            printf("Introduceti o optiune valida");
            break;
        }

    } while (option != 0);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add snippet of Error also.

Comment: You need to enable compiler warnings/errors.  The line `return aux[30];` is attempting to return the element at index 30 in `aux`.  There are several problems with this:  (1) index 30 is out of bounds, (2) `aux[30]` has type `char`, not `char *` as required, (3) even if you "fixed" it by issuing `return aux;`, it still wouldn't work because `aux` is a local variable that ceases to exist after the function returns.

Comment: @SkkyDMG What compiler are you using?  What warnings are enabled?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica i'm using VS code , not sure how can i check that

Comment: @TomKarzes well , it was a problem from a class and it worked for the one that solved it

Comment: @SkkyDMG Code, as posted, would not work  for the one that solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't waste time typing in 15 'prompts' and 15 case labels as if adding more code will get things working. I strongly suggest deleting that code (or commenting out those lines) and focus your attention on the tiny utility pieces that you need to build upon.

Here's a 'fixed' version of `reverse()` to get you going. PLEASE work incrementally, testing every tiny extra line of code added, every tiny change you make. Mountains don't grow from the top down...

```
char *reverse( char *str ) {
    for( int i = 0, j = strlen( str ) - 1; i <= j; i++, j-- ) {
        char tmp = str[i];
        str[i] = str[j];
        str[j] = tmp;
    }
    return str;
}

int main() {
    char *str[] = { "the fish", "goats are good" };

    printf( "%s", str[0] );
    printf( " == %s\n", reverse( str[0] ) );

    printf( "%s", str[1] );
    printf( " == %s\n", reverse( str[1] ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
the fish == hsif eht
goats are good == doog era staog
```

EDIT:

Because of criticism leveled at this answer, I feel dutybound to add this note.

Because this function reverses the string "in place", you will need to adapt the following line of code:

```
strcpy( (product + *n)->productCode, reverse((product + *n)->productName) );
```

to

```
reverse( strcpy( (product + *n)->productCode, (product + *n)->productName) );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , i was working in the same rythm as them , so i might got lost somewhere between the lines ,...about that prompt lines , it;s part of the problem , they require it :// thanks for the advice <3

Comment: @SkkyDMG Are their fingers on the keyboard, their eyes looking at the screen? In the short term, ELIMINATE as much as you can (comment it out) so you can focus on one aspect at a time. Today is not Christmas, but we'll get there eventually...

Comment: you're right:) i am at university so yeah , kinda go how they want

Comment: Your `reverse()` function doesn't work. Take time, as I did, to write a tiny program, as I did, and get the function 'reverse()` to work, as I did... Then, if the code is put-together well, you can simply drop that function from your tiny test program into the bigger program you are trying to make functional. FOCUS on tiny bits, and the whole will emerge... Good luck.

Comment: This “answer” neither answers the question nor fixes the code. (a) The 15 prompts and case labels are not an attempt to get things working by adding more code. They are prompts and labels for functions intended to be added to the program later. (b) There is no explanation of why the code in the question is wrong. (c) There is no explanation of how the code in the answer works and how it differs from the original code. (d) The code in the answer is not right because it reverses a string in place, but that corrupts the `productName` member; in-place reversal is not wanted.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Nor did I complete the incomplete (absent) 13 other functions of the school project. Jus want to make sure your list of objections is as complete as possible. (This `reverse()` works... The OP can use `strcpy()` to first copy the product name to the product code field, THEN reverse that field in place... Please chill out... I'm not taking the course. I'm trying to suggest how to approach a programing challenge... Thank you for your insights...

Comment: @EricPostpischil I have added an EDIT to this answer to clarify how this `reverse( )` can be used.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this acknowledged "code dump" revision of the original code (with a sprinkling of comments) to demonstrate how the "big picture" sketch can coexist with incremental development. Please study this example from the entry point of `main()` to the `exit()` of `case 0:`. Note how shorter names 'clarify' what the code in functions does. When you are tempted to "copy/paste/adapt" some lines of code, ask yourself if the functionality could be better served by breaking out a separate function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Product {
    char name[30]; // meaningful but shorter name
    char code[30]; // meaningful but shorter name
    int price;
    int stock;
    int exp_yr, exp_mo, exp_dy; // no confusion
} P_t; // conventional to use "_t" with tokens 'typedef'd

// primative 'helper' functions
char *getString( char *prompt, char *to, int len ) {
    printf( "%s", prompt );
    fgets( to, len, stdin );
    to[ strlen(to) - 1 ] = '\0'; // get rid of '\n'
    return to;
}

int getInt( char *prompt ) {
    char buf[32];
    return atoi( getString( prompt, buf, sizeof buf ) );
}

char *reverse( char *str ) { // "in place" string reversal
    int lft = 0;
    int rgt = strlen( str ) - 1;

    for( ; lft <= rgt; lft++, rgt-- ) {
        char tmp = str[ lft ];
        str[ lft ] = str[ rgt ];
        str[ rgt ] = tmp;
    }
    return str;
}

int nameValid( char *str ) { // check for bad chars
    if( *str == '\0' ) return 0; // At least one char required

    char *permitted = "- abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; // extra acceptable chars

    return strspn( str, permitted ) == strlen( str ); // true if all chars okay
}

void input( P_t *pp ) { // fill-in ONE record
    do {
        getString( "Product name: ", pp->name, sizeof pp->name );
    } while( !nameValid( pp->name ) );

    reverse( strcpy( pp->code, pp->name ) );
    printf( "Product Code: %s\n", pp->code );

    pp->price = getInt( "Price: " );
    pp->stock = getInt( "In stock: " );

    // Not good, but sufficient
    while( ( pp->exp_dy = getInt( "Exp. day: " ) ) < 1 || pp->exp_dy > 31 ) {} // loop

    while( ( pp->exp_mo = getInt( "Exp. month: " ) ) < 1 || pp->exp_mo > 12 ) {} // loop

    pp->exp_yr = getInt( "Exp. year: " );
}

// Renamed to show outputs multiple records
// Equivalent, but easier to think of as array
void outputAll( P_t prod[], int n ) {

    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) { // NB: changed '<=' to '<'
        P_t *pp = &prod[ i ]; // less verbose

        printf( "Product name: %10s ", pp->name );
        printf( "Price: %5d ", pp->price );
        printf( "Stock:%5d", pp->stock );
        printf( "\n" ); // Clearly 'end of line'
    }
}

int main() {
    P_t product[100]; // uninitialised
    int count = 0;

    memset( product, 0, sizeof product ); // Now initialised

    for( ;; ) {
        printf(
            "\n0.Iesire\n" );
        printf(
            "1.Citirea unui produs de la tastatura\n" );
        printf(
            "2.Afisarea produselor citite\n" );
/*      printf(
            "3.Afisarea produselor cu un pret mai mic dat de utilizator\n" );
        printf(
            "4.Sa se afiseze toate produsele care au lungimea numelui egala cu un numar par\n" );
        printf(
            "5.Afisarea primului produs care este egal cu un nume dat de utilizator\n" );
        printf(
            "6.Sa se realizeze produsul cifrelor fiecarui numar de bucati al produselor, "
            "apoi sa se copieze fiecare produs intr-un vector si sa se afiseze vectorul.\n" );
        printf(
            "7.Copierea tuturor codurilor produselor intr-un vector de sir de caractere, "
            "apoi afisare vectorului\n" );
        printf(
            "8.Copierea pretului produselor intr-un vector "
            "apoi afisarea vectorului in ordine crescatoare\n" );
        printf(
            "9.Sa se transforme prima litera din codul "
            "produsului in litera mare daca aceasta este vocala. "
            "Nu se vor folosii functii predefinite in schimbarea literei\n" );
        printf(
            "10.Sa se afiseze forma binara a numarului de bucati "
            "ale produselor care au numarul de bucati mai mic decat 100 .\n" );
        printf(
            "11.Sa se afiseze toate produsele care urmeaza sa expire in urmatoarele 10 zile. "
            "Utilizator va preciza de la tastatura ziua si luna curenta.\n" );
        printf(
            "12.Sa se pun pe ultimul rand al unei matrici de caractere de ordin "
            "dat de numarul de produse, primul caracter "
            "din fieacre nume de produs,pe restul '.'\n" );
        printf(
            "13.Stabilirea unui nou pret pt toate produsele daca utilizatorul "
            "doreste.Astfel utilizator va stabili procentajul cu "
             "care se vor scumpi produsele.\n" );
        printf(
            "14.Sa se stearga un produs precizat de utilizator prin numele acestuia\n" );
*/

        switch ( getInt( "Introduceti o optiune: " ) ) {
            case 0:
                exit( 1 ); // Would 'return 0' be better?
                break;

            case 1:
                // increment it here, instead of using pointer there.
                // pass only one element to be filled in.
                input( &product[ count++ ] );
                break;

            case 2:
                outputAll( product, count );
                break;

// ToDo:
//          case 3: break;
//          case 4: break;
//          case 5: break;
//          case 6: break;
//          case 7: break;
//          case 8: break;
//          case 9: break;
//          case 10: break;
//          case 11: break;
//          case 12: break;
//          case 13: break;
//          case 14: break;
// End ToDo

            default:
                printf("Introduceti o optiune valida");
                break;
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```